# Adsense shows I have ads.txt errors, but also says everything is okay

Tags: adsense

AdSense shows I have an issue with ads.txt -- however, when clicking "Fix Now" it claims everything is okay (approval status AND ads.txt status).

I AM seeing ads on my site.

Why does the error message persist? [image]

Answer (score 0):

this is a known bug. The problem is with Google AdSense. Do not worry about it.